# Devices menu - project to second screen with only one monitor

Tags: windows-8

So I made a huge blunder. In the devices menu on Windows 8, I selected  to project to a second screen only on accident. I had two monitors connected but only the primary one was actually displaying anything. So I projected it and now I can't access anything. The primary screen will show the windows icon when it loads, but then it disappears and I can't login or anything. Surely there's a way to get it back on the primary screen?

Thanks a bunch. I'm really lost..

Comment: Have you tried Windows-P and then "disconnect projector" ?

Comment: Would that work before I even get to the login screen? The sequence goes like this: computer turns on, the motherboard screen flashes up, I get the Windows Logo for about 2 seconds and then the primary screen goes to "No Signal". Then the secondary screen will show a light gray background with the mouse cursor on it. That's where I get stuck and can't do anything but move the mouse around.

Comment: You could [try starting Windows 8 in Safe Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/), change a few settings then reboot?

Comment: Might give that a shot, though it will likely still boot onto "my second screen". But we'll see what happens. Might have to do a full reset of the machine.

Comment: Just to clarify, you set Windows to display on multiple monitors although you have just one?

Answer (score -1):

Press and hold <kbd>Windows</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> together. Press <kbd>down</kbd> once and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>